# how to express (5 x 5.4 10-3) in objective-c

Tags: c++, objective-c, math

I am trying to convert from meter to nautical miles.
I need to multiply meters by 5.4x10<sup>-3</sup> but I am not sure how express this number in objective-c.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: What part of that multiplication are you having trouble with?

Comment: You mean 5.4 * 10^-3?? int that case just use: float miles = (meters*5.4)/1000

Comment: Why is this tagged as both `c++` and `objective-c` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
double factor = 5.4e-3;
```

This means: 5.4 times 10 to the power -3.